# Enable a disabled input field by default when checkbox is checked in angular

Tags: angular, checkbox, disabled-input, formgroups, isenabled

I am creating a form group with a checkbox in Angular 13. Here, the field of receiver code is disabled by default. How can I enable this input field when the checkbox is checked and disable when it's not?

in my .ts I have:

```
export class IntPayComponent implements OnInit { 
     paymentDetails!: FormGroup;
     disabled = true; 

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.paymentDetails = this._formBuilder.group({
  receiver_code: new FormControl({value:"", disabled: true})
});
}
```

and in my html template I have:

```
<mat-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
   <mat-step [stepControl]="paymentDetails">
      <form [formGroup]="paymentDetails">
         <div class="add-directory">
            <mat-checkbox>Add to Directory</mat-checkbox>
         </div>
         <div class="reference-field">
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill" floatLabel="always">
               <mat-label>Receiver Code</mat-label>
                  <input matInput formControlName="receiver_code"/> 
            </mat-form-field>
         </div>
      </form>
   </mat-step>
</mat-stepper>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the checkbox into a FormControl, say `addDirectory`:

```js
this.paymentDetails = this._formBuilder.group({
  receiver_code: new FormControl({value:"", disabled: true}),
  addDirectory: new FormControl(false)
});
```

Then, after the `FormGroup` initialisation, you listen to its `valueChanges` Observable and modify `receiver_code`'s disabled state accordingly:

```js
this.paymentDetails.get('addDirectory').valueChanges.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroy$), // make sure you implement an unsubscribe strategy
  tap(addCtrlValue => {
    const receiverCtrl = this.paymentDetails.get('receiver_code');
    addCtrlValue ? receiverCtrl.enable() : receiverCtrl.disable();
  })
).subscribe();
```

You could make things a bit cleaner by setting the `FormControls` up as independent from the `FormGroup`, meaning you don't have to keep calling `get` to get access to them.

Also, FYI, you don't use the HTML `disabled` attribute when working with reactive forms. No doubt Angular has displayed a warning about this in the console.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to angular, please bear with me. I don't know why but on my end `this.paymentDetails.get('addDirectory')` generates an error showing that `Object is possibly 'null'`

Comment: @Will, it's unnecesary create an "addDirectory" FormControl.

Comment: @Eliseo when you want to react to changes in form elements, reactive forms are almost always the best solution. This answer is cleaner, more readable, and more easily maintained and understood than yours. Template forms should not be used when reactive forms provide the cleanest approach. It is always better to avoid putting logic in the template.

Comment: @nanakyoong you can add a `!` so TypeScript knows the control will exist, because you know for certain that it does (having initialised it just beforehand).

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the "output" change of the mat-checkbox

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="paymentDetails.get('receiver_code')
           [$event.checked?'enable':'disable']()">
      Add to Directory
</mat-checkbox>
```

You can also use a simple checkbox if you're using a simple input type checkbox (or you want not use (change) event-

```
  <mat-checkbox [ngModel]="enable" 
                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
                (ngModelChange)="enable=$event;
                  paymentDetails.get('receiver_code')[$event?'enable':'disable']()"

  >Add to Directory</mat-checkbox>
```

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-material-starter-template-pzyanp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) with both aproach

NOTE: Not always need "change" our FormGroup. if only want to change the "apparence" of the .html it's better use a new variable that not belong to the FormGroup or another method

Comment: This answer places far too much unnecessary logic in the template, and uses template-driven forms when reactive forms are the obvious choice here. This may well work, but it is certainly not the cleanest approach.

Comment: @WillAlexander in this case, I'm not agree with you. In my opinion the .html is only a "recipient". For me "enable/disable" an input is not very different to change the color or background-color of one div, so I use a "variable" to change it. It's the reason I see that the enable/disable belongs to the "logic of the .html" (not the logic of the component). You can change the .html -e.g. now you use a button or you can make invisible the input- and you needn't change the .ts- (but I repeat, it's only a personal opinion).

Comment: Enabling and disabling in a reactive form (which OP is using) is definitely not HTML-based. In fact, Angular will throw a warning if you use the HTML disabled attribute inside a reactive form. There’s no real space for opinion here: there may not be only one correct approach, but there certainly are incorrect ones, and I’m afraid your approach is incorrect, from an Angular viewpoint.